# what are some cross-language libraries for people who know other languages (similar to phpjs)

Tags: comparison, interop, language-comparisons, phpjs

PHPJS attempts to port php functions over to javascript.

http://phpjs.org/

Rationale: people who know php's functions really well can write javascript and just carry over what they know from php into the javascript world

**Question:** I would like to know if there are other language libraries where someone ported concepts from language X into language Y, just like with phpjs.

If you know of such a library, can you please answer here with the name of it and what languages are being used?

**IMPORTANT:** this is not a question about javascript or PHP. I am interested in knowing as many as possible names of different language libraries that attempt to 'bridge' between any two arbitrary languages.

PHPJS is just an example of the kind of critter I am looking for.

**UPDATE:**

- http://haxe.org/ is one possible answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**XMLVM**](http://www.xmlvm.org)
[image]
<sub>(source: [xmlvm.org](http://www.xmlvm.org/overview/overview.jpg))</sub>  
Java, C#, Python -> Obj-C, Android Apps